# Common word count across a table, not just a row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know I can count common occurrences of words in a string but what's the best solution for mulitple strings? Or in this case, rows in a table?

Example table:

```
ID    Title
------------
1     red car
2     blue car
3     red bike
4     green car
5     red and green car
```

I want to return the top 3 common words and their count from column: title e.g.

```
Word    Count
--------------
car     4
red     3
green   2
```

I'm using mysql & PHP

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Normalize your data

Comment: I don't think that degree of normalization is appropriate. It's not necessary to solve every problem using only MySQL.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Consider accepting one of the two Answers or ask for further Detail. This will prevent this Question from getting any more Attention and also show at least some appreciation for the people who took the time to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done with MySQL using it's [string manipulation methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/string-functions.html). Using those, you can create a query getting you all "words" from your table rows.
However, splitting a string in MySQL is not a trivial problem. Sadly MySQL has no split or explode method.
Read about it [here](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/).

If you use that query as a subquery, you can use order by and the string length method of MySQL to get an ordered list of words and their occurance.

Your alternative is to iterate over all MySQL Results, filling a local PHP Array with the words you find and keep count. See in this example:

```
<?php
// connect to db and so fort
...
$wordCounterArray = array();
while(($row = mysqlfetch_assoc($mysqlHandle) !== false ) {
  $words = explode(' ',$row['Title']);
  foreach ($words as $word) {
    if(array_key_exists($word, $wordCounterArray ) {
      $wordCounterArray[$word]++;
    }
    else {
      $wordCounterArray[$word] = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Now you still have to sort that array by its values, but i guess you will figure out how to do that yourself with google and the php online documentation right?

Answer (score 0):

use this to fetch a record :

```
SELECT group_concat(concat(`Title`) separator ' ')
FROM test
```

see [<kbd>demo</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/820884/2)

store it value into **$text** then use,

```
echo substr_count($text, 'car');
echo substr_count($text, 'red');
```

for more detail about **substr_count()** see [demo](https://www.php.net/substr_count)

Comment: won't you run into problems if the resulting string gets too long?
Are there no restrictions for how long a single row result field can be in MySQL?